# Is it possible to save data at client side without use of session?

Tags: http, browser

I want to save user data at **client side** after page load or after ajax request for later use that's help to not look back to server database.

Comment: By session, do you mean to include cookies? If not, just use cookies.

Comment: Storing it in a cookie is your only option, but this can be easily manipulated which is why the user data is usually stored on the server side and the cookie just points to a reference.

Comment: is it possible to for large data set?

Comment: @RahulMurari what do you mean by large? 4kB or 1MB?

Comment: @Mahdi **No**, i m looking for user's data set, if we used session so that's so complex, i am looking for later purpose because session will _expired_ after some time so i don't want to deal with session.

Comment: @RahulMurari I've updated the answer with more details.

Answer (score 3):

First `Cookies` and then `HTML 5 Local Storage` can helps you!

P.S. *Session* mostly sounds like a *server-side* stuff.

**Update**

Regarding your comment: *because session will expired after some time so i don't want to deal with session.*

If you're really need to save the user state somehow, and you want to keep it for a long time. You can:

1. Look at the vendor manual of your Web Server; Increase the Session Timeout value.
2. Store the users' data set (a.k.a. User Session) into a persistence storage: Serialize the array, store it in your database system.
3. Store the Session ID or UserID in the *Browsers' Cookie* or *HTML5 Local Storage*, and retrieve it next time, look into the database and load that complex and large data set into the user session again.
4. Think about the security of what you're doing ...

Answer (score 0):

on client side you shall use  JavaScript  localStorage , but its availible only modern browsers and IE > 8